# Android: Is there any way of speeding up canvas.drawBitmap?

Tags: android, performance, sprite, tablet, frame-rate

Simple question, not sure sure there's a simple answer though!!

Is there anything at all that I can do to speed up my surfaceview drawing?

I'm using something like this:

```
c.drawBitmap(scaledSprite, X, Y, redPaint);
```

The method that I'm using has to draw about 25 of these sprites on the screen, so I'm using a for loop, meaning it has to display 25 during a frame.

Now, this works absolutely fine on the 3 phones that I've tested on, but on a tablet, it just slows down.  I've commented out all the other drawing methods and left just this one and this is definitely what is slowing the game down.

Are there any clever tips anyone can give me to speed this up?

I know open GL is a possibility but the bulk of the game is now written so I don't really want to make any drastic changes now if I can help it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you set your SurfaceView to lower quality graphics

```
getHolder().setFormat(0x00000004); //RGB_565
```

and load all bitmaps in the same config

```
Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inScaled = false; 
options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
```

This would make it faster, plus you would need to make variable movement speed of sprites depending on the frame delay.

However, even with these settings an arcade game with many sprites will not work well on a tablet, hence, I am afraid, if you want to make a proper game that sells, you must create an OpenGl framework or use ready made ones.

Comment: Hey, thank you that's great! It did help - I found out what the major problem was also, I was using a grey sprite which I was colouring using the paint option of drawBitmap - I have no idea why but doing that slows it down to a snails pace, so I will have to create different coloured sprites and load them - but the combination of that and your suggestion has helped me lots - it runs great now!!

Comment: Yes, I think the best is that Paint is null for quick drawing of bitmaps. But occasional coloring by filter should work fine.

Comment: FWIW, if you want to avoid bloating your .apk with duplicated graphics which are just different colorizations of the same image, you could just include the grey one in your resources, and create colorized bitmaps at run-time (once, not every frame) ... I've had good success speeding up an app of mine with similar prerendering techniques

Comment: this is awsome...it increased the Speed a lot. I read about `RGB_565` long time before, but thought that this would decrease quality dramatically. But it doesn´t , for simple bitmaps like a one colored shape it works. Great answer....