# Android createBitmap(...) with RGB_565 option instead of ARGB_8888 do not show most of tiles

Tags: java, android, kotlin, surfaceview

I am trying to improve speed of my drawing bitmap (bitmaps are made in Tiled application). I read that I can try to use RGB_565 option instead of ARGB_8888 when it comes to `createBitmap(...)` last argument. I also set `getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGB_565)` in the constructors of my custom SurfaceView class like somebody said in this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/14615533/21172734.

Now **what I want is** to display all tiles on the screen because now only one of them shows up (because of changing Bitmap option from ARGB_8888 to RGB_565).

<s>The problem is that when I set this RGB_565 in all those places the bitmaps are not drawing and I get blank screen but when there is ARGB_8888 set I have my bitmaps correctly displayed but slow. According to TinyDancer library with RGB_565 (empty screen) I get 60FPS while with ARGB_8888  I get only 20FPS so I want to improve it as much as possible.</s>

**EDIT**

It turned out my map somehow displays but only one layer, and this layer is even displayed partialy (only one tile). The majority of tiles don't show up. Before, I didn't notice that simply because my map was quite big. Now I reduce its size almost to minimum (8x8) and this map visual might makes no sense but it is for learning purposes and then later on making a tiled based game.

Now, how it should looks like (screenshot from Tiled app). 'Grass' layer is static layer of grass but layer 'anim' is located in two places this tree  and moshrooms and they animate, tree - three frames of anim, moshrooms - two frames of anim:

[image]

And the only one tile that is displayed in phone when Bitmap.Config.RGB_565 is set. I bordered it with yellow circle

[image]:

ARGB_8888 displays all tiles correctly, but as I said before I want RGB_565 because of better performance:

**EDIT2**

Here is my code.

GameMainSurface.java

```
public class GameMainSurface extends GameSurface implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

(...)

    public GameMainSurface(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
        getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGB_565);
        getHolder().addCallback(this);
        setWillNotDraw(false);
    }

    public GameMainSurface(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.context = context;
        getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGB_565);
        getHolder().addCallback(this);
        setWillNotDraw(false);
    }

    public GameMainSurface(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        this.context = context;
        getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGB_565);
        getHolder().addCallback(this);
        setWillNotDraw(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.draw(canvas);

        Loader.drawTmxMaps(canvas, getContext());

        invalidate();
    }

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    this.holder = holder;
    (...)
    initMaps();
}

protected void initMaps() {
    TileMapData tileMainMapData = TmxLoader.readTMX("map_main4.tmx", context);
    TmxLoader.createBitmaps(tileMainMapData, 0, 4, this);
 } 
}
```

Loader.java

```
public class Loader {

private static final String TAG = TmxLoader.class.getSimpleName();

private static final Map<Integer, Bitmap[]> framesMap = new HashMap<>();
private static final Map<Integer, Canvas[]> canvasesMap = new HashMap<>();
private static final Map<Integer, Long> animsDuration = new HashMap<>();
private static final List<Runnable> runnables = new ArrayList<>();
private static final Handler handler = new Handler();

private static boolean isIterStarted = false;

(...)

public static TileMapData readTMX(String filename, Context c) {
    TileMapData tileMapData = null;

    // Initialize SAX
    try {

        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser parser = spf.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader reader = parser.getXMLReader();

        // Create an instance of the TMX XML handler
        // that will create a TileMapData object
        TmxHandler handler = new TmxHandler();

        reader.setContentHandler(handler);

        AssetManager assetManager = c.getAssets();

        reader.parse((new InputSource(assetManager.open(filename))));

        // Extract the created object
        tileMapData = handler.getData();


    } catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
        Log.e(TAG, "SAX XML parse error", pce);
    } catch (SAXException se) {
        Log.e(TAG, "SAX XML error", se);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        Log.e(TAG, "SAX XML parse io error", ioe);
    }

    return tileMapData;
}

public static void createBitmaps(TileMapData t, int startLayer, int endLayer, GameSurface gameSurface) {

    try {
        AssetManager assetManager = gameSurface.getContext().getAssets();

        Bitmap[] tilesets = new Bitmap[t.tilesets.size()];

        for (int i = 0; i < tilesets.length; i++) {
            tilesets[i] = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(assetManager.open(t.tilesets.get(i).ImageFilename));
        }

        long currentGID;
        Long localGID;
        Integer currentTileSetIndex;
        Rect source = new Rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
        Rect dest = new Rect(0, 0, 0, 0);

        boolean isAfterInit = false;
        List<Integer> animFrames = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = startLayer; i < endLayer; i++) {
            // endlessblow_main4.tmx = 12
            for (int j = 0; j < t.layers.get(i).height; j++) {
                // endlessblow_main4.tmx = 8
                for (int k = 0; k < t.layers.get(i).width; k++) {

                    currentGID = t.getGIDAt(k, j, i);
                    localGID = t.getLocalID(currentGID);
                    currentTileSetIndex = t.getTileSetIndex(currentGID);



                    if (!isAfterInit) {
                        animFrames = Stream.of(t.tilesets.get(currentTileSetIndex).tileAnimations).map(tileAnimation -> tileAnimation.getTileFrames().size()).collect(Collectors.toList());
                        for (int l = 0; l < t.tilesets.get(currentTileSetIndex).tileAnimations.size(); l++) {
                            for (int m = 0; m < t.tilesets.get(currentTileSetIndex).tileAnimations.get(l).getTileFrames().size(); m++) {
                                animsDuration.put(l, t.tilesets.get(currentTileSetIndex).tileAnimations.get(l).getTileFrames().get(m).getDuration());
                            }
                        }
                        init(animFrames, t);
                        isAfterInit = true;
                    }

                    if (localGID != null) {
                        if (i == startLayer) {
                            source.top = (((localGID).intValue()) / ((t.tilesets.get(currentTileSetIndex).imageWidth) / t.tilewidth)) * t.tileheight;
                            source.left = (((localGID).intValue()) % ((t.tilesets.get(currentTileSetIndex).imageWidth) / t.tilewidth)) * t.tilewidth;
                            source.bottom = source.top + t.tileheight;
                            source.right = source.left + t.tilewidth;

                            dest.top = j * t.tileheight;
                            dest.left = k * t.tilewidth;
                            dest.bottom = dest.top + t.tileheight;
                            dest.right = dest.left + t.tilewidth;

                            for (Canvas canvas : canvasesMap.get(0)) {
                                canvas.drawBitmap(tilesets[currentTileSetIndex], source, dest, null);
                            }
                        } else {
                            for (int l = 0; l < t.tilesets.get(currentTileSetIndex).tileAnimations.size(); l++) {

                                if (localGID == t.tilesets.get(currentTileSetIndex).tileAnimations.get(l).getLocalGID()) {
                                    for (int frame = 0; frame < t.tilesets.get(currentTileSetIndex).tileAnimations.get(l).getTileFrames().size(); frame++) {

                                        source.top = (int) ((t.tilesets.get(currentTileSetIndex).tileAnimations.get(l).getTileFrames().get(frame).getTileId() / ((t.tilesets.get(currentTileSetIndex).imageWidth) / t.tilewidth)) * t.tileheight);
                                        source.left = (int) ((t.tilesets.get(currentTileSetIndex).tileAnimations.get(l).getTileFrames().get(frame).getTileId() % ((t.tilesets.get(currentTileSetIndex).imageWidth) / t.tilewidth)) * t.tilewidth);
                                        source.bottom = source.top + t.tileheight;
                                        source.right = source.left + t.tilewidth;

                                        dest.top = j * t.tileheight;
                                        dest.left = k * t.tilewidth;
                                        dest.bottom = dest.top + t.tileheight;
                                        dest.right = dest.left + t.tilewidth;

                                        canvasesMap.get(l)[frame].drawBitmap(tilesets[currentTileSetIndex], source, dest, null);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < framesMap.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < animFrames.get(i); j++) {
                framesMap.get(i)[j] = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(framesMap.get(i)[j], gameSurface.getCellWidth() * t.width, gameSurface.getCellHeight() * t.height, false);
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
    }
}


private static void init(List<Integer> animFrames, TileMapData t) {
    for (int i = 0; i < animFrames.size(); i++) {
        runnables.add(new FrameDurationRunnable(animFrames.get(i), animsDuration.get(i)));
        framesMap.put(i, new Bitmap[animFrames.get(i)]);
        canvasesMap.put(i, new Canvas[animFrames.get(i)]);
        for (int j = 0; j < animFrames.get(i); j++) {
            framesMap.get(i)[j] = Bitmap.createBitmap(t.width * t.tilewidth, t.height * t.tileheight, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
            canvasesMap.get(i)[j] = new Canvas(framesMap.get(i)[j]);
        }
    }
}


public static void drawTmxMaps(Canvas canvas, Context context) {
    for (int i = 0; i < framesMap.size(); i++) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(framesMap.get(i)[((FrameDurationRunnable) runnables.get(i)).iter], 0, 0, null);
    }

    if (!isIterStarted) {
        iterTmxFrames();
        isIterStarted = true;
    }
}


private static void iterTmxFrames() {
    for (int i = 0; i < runnables.size(); i++) {
        handler.postDelayed(runnables.get(i), animsDuration.get(i));
    }
}

private static class FrameDurationRunnable implements Runnable {
    private final int animMaxIter;
    private final long frameDuration;

    private int iter;

    FrameDurationRunnable(final int animMaxIter, final long frameDuration) {
        this.animMaxIter = animMaxIter;
        this.frameDuration = frameDuration;
    }

    public void run() {
        iter++;
        if (iter == animMaxIter) iter = 0;
        handler.postDelayed(this, frameDuration);
    }
}
}
```

What solutions do you see?

Comment: You'd need to show us the actual code you're trying to optimize.  There's too many things you could be doing wrong to guess from a description

Comment: But if 565 gets your 60fps and 8888 gets your 25, and 565 doesn't display correctly, odds are it's not actually doing any work.

Comment: Hi @GabeSechan I added the important code. I hope it is quite understandable...